# Slow Query in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, query, speedoptimization, slow-response

I have continuously found below query in my slow query log, It seems the query is used for the site navigation. 
It has done the re-indexing and flush the cache but still the same.

Here is the query:

```
SQL: SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS `name`, IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) AS `is_active`, IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) AS `include_in_menu`, `core_url_rewrite`.`request_path` FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = '41') AND `at_name_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = '41') AND (`at_name`.`store_id` = 1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active_default` ON (`at_is_active_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active_default`.`attribute_id` = '42') AND `at_is_active_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active` ON (`at_is_active`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active`.`attribute_id` = '42') AND (`at_is_active`.`store_id` = 1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu_default` ON (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`attribute_id` = '67') AND `at_include_in_menu_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu` ON (`at_include_in_menu`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`attribute_id` = '67') AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`store_id` = 1)
 LEFT JOIN `core_url_rewrite` ON (core_url_rewrite.category_id=e.entity_id) AND (core_url_rewrite.is_system=1 AND core_url_rewrite.store_id='1' AND core_url_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'category/%') WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '3') AND (`e`.`entity_id` IN('3', '322', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '300', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '93', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99', '100', '101', '102', '94', '103', '105', '106', '107', '108', '109', '104', '320', '341', '110', '111', '112', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '119', '113', '120', '122', '123', '124', '125', '126', '127', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132', '133', '304', '121', '298', '134', '135', '136', '137', '138', '139', '140', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '299', '325', '328', '146', '147', '149', '150', '151', '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '148', '157', '158', '159', '160', '161', '162', '163', '164', '165', '166', '167', '168', '170', '169', '171', '173', '174', '175', '176', '177', '178', '179', '180', '181', '182', '183', '184', '185', '186', '187', '188', '189', '190', '191', '192', '193', '194', '195', '196', '197', '198', '199', '200', '201', '202', '203', '204', '205', '172', '206', '207', '208', '210', '211', '209', '212', '214', '215', '216', '217', '218', '213', '321', '342', '219', '220', '222', '223', '224', '226', '227', '228', '229', '230', '231', '232', '233', '234', '235', '236', '237', '238', '239', '240', '241', '242', '305', '338', '221', '225', '331', '243', '245', '246', '247', '248', '249', '250', '244', '251', '252', '253', '255', '254', '256', '258', '259', '260', '261', '262', '263', '257', '264', '266', '267', '268', '269', '270', '265', '271', '273', '272', '274', '276', '277', '275', '323', '339', '278', '280', '281', '282', '279', '327', '303', '306', '344', '343', '340', '334', '335', '336', '337', '319', '307', '316', '308', '317', '330', '309', '310', '311', '312', '313', '314', '315', '318', '326', '329')) AND (`e`.`entity_id` NOT IN('169', '320', '321', '328')) AND (IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) = '1') AND (IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) = '1') ORDER BY `name` ASC
AFF: 315
TIME: 2.1247
```

Any suggestion to resolve it.

Comment: You can add indexing to the MySQL table to resolve the slow query issue.

Comment: already done, as this query is from magento's table already have indexes